# UNAuthorizationOptionProvisional not showing notification permission alert while using react-native

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-firebase

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/messaging. for Push notification.

i am using

```
await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
```

to request permission but it not showing permission alert.

After debugging i found

```
 RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(requestPermission:
  (RCTPromiseResolveBlock) resolve
    :(RCTPromiseRejectBlock) reject
) {
  if (RCTRunningInAppExtension()) {
    [RNFBSharedUtils rejectPromiseWithUserInfo:reject userInfo:[@{
        @"code": @"unavailable-in-extension",
        @"message": @"requestPermission can not be called in App Extensions"} mutableCopy]];
    return;
  }

  if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions;
    if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
      authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionProvisional | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;

    } else {
      authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;

    }
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *_Nullable error) {
      if (error) {
        [RNFBSharedUtils rejectPromiseWithNSError:reject error:error];
      } else {
        resolve(@([RCTConvert BOOL:@(granted)]));
      }
    }];
  } else {
    // TODO community iOS 9 support could be added here with `registerUserNotificationSettings:settings` & `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings`
    [RNFBSharedUtils rejectPromiseWithUserInfo:reject userInfo:[@{
        @"code": @"unsupported-platform-version",
        @"message": @"requestPermission call failed; minimum supported version requirement not met (iOS 10)."} mutableCopy]];
  }

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
  });
}
```

if i change

```
if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
  authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionProvisional | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;

}
```

to

```
 if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
  authOptions =  UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;

}
```

It works fine. but how can i change that setting from react-native project.

Above is in pod framework it will be remove when i update. is there any way i can remove UNAuthorizationOptionProvisional from react-native